# How to cast variadic arguments to a container class?

Tags: c++

I'm working on something that allows me to make it easier to call functions in a scripting language (Lua) and one idea was to use variadic arguments. There are two ways to do that:

```
Call( int count, ... )
```

and

```
Call( const char* args, ... )
```

like printf. I thought the first one would be a little easier to maintain, so I tried doing it by making a wrapper to manage types of arguments. It looks like this:

```
class ArgWrapper
{
public:
    ArgWrapper();

    ArgWrapper( const int& v ) { val.i = v; type = INT; }
    ArgWrapper( const bool& v ) { val.b = v; type = BOOL; }
    ArgWrapper( const float& v ) { val.f = v; type = FLOAT; }
    ArgWrapper( const double& v ) { val.d = v; type = DOUBLE; }

    operator int() { return val.i; }
    operator bool() { return val.b; }
    operator float() { return val.f; }
    operator double() { return val.d; }

    enum {
        INT,
        BOOL,
        FLOAT,
        DOUBLE
    } type;

    union
    {
        int i;
        bool b;
        float f;
        double d;
    } val;
};
```

This works fine and dandy, but when I actually try to make this work in a varadic arguments construction, it turns out that the values aren't actually casted.

```
void printArgs( int c, ArgWrapper... )
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start( ap, c );

    for ( int i = 0; i < c; i++ )
    {
        ArgWrapper arg = va_arg( ap, ArgWrapper );
        if ( arg.type == arg.INT ) std::cout << "integer - " << (int)arg << std::endl;
        if ( arg.type == arg.BOOL ) std::cout << "boolean - " << std::boolalpha << (bool)arg << std::endl;
        if ( arg.type == arg.FLOAT ) std::cout << "float - " << (float)arg << std::endl;
        if ( arg.type == arg.DOUBLE ) std::cout << "double - " << (double)arg << std::endl;
    }

    va_end( ap );
}

...

printArgs( 4, 1337.0f, 18, 37.0, true );
```

The above results in garbage, while this works perfectly fine:

```
printArgs( 4, (ArgWrapper)1337.0f, (ArgWrapper)18, (ArgWrapper)37.0, (ArgWrapper)true );
```

How do I specify that each variadic argument should have the same common type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use C++03, you can't, since variadic arguments using the c-style ellipsis `...` do not carry type information in any way. This is why stuff like `printf()` uses format specifiers, since it needs a way to know what to cast stuff to.

When you can use C++11, you should use variadic templates right away which would make any kind of helper like your ArgWrapper unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

When and if you have a C++ compiler that supports the initializer list feature from C++11 you can write your printArgs function as

```
#include <initializer_list>

void printArgs(std::initializer_list<ArgWrapper> args) {
  for (const ArgWrapper *arg = args.begin(), *end = args.end; arg != end; ++arg) {
    /* process arg */
  } 
}
```

and call it like

```
printArgs({ 4, 1337.0f, 18, 37.0, true });
```

This can sometimes be an easier route than variadic templates.

Answer (score 0):

Variadic templates to the rescue:

```
template <typename ...Args>
R call(int n, Args &&... args)
{
    return printArgs(n, ArgWrapper(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
}
```

This is assuming that your `printArgs` function must actually use C-style variadic arguments. There are reasons for and against it; if everything is C++ you have a few alternatives.